# when I select from kendodropdownlist and send data to function I have to reload the page to clear data out

Tags: jquery, ajax, kendo-ui

I have a kendo ui for jquery grid. In the first column cell there is a kendodropdownllist drop down that has a select function set on it. And when a person selects an option I get that row's data, the drop down selection, pop up a model window, validate the user input into the window, and use "send()" to send the data to a back end API call. I a if/else set on validator.validate() so that I capture and alert fail messages but in the done I hide the modal window. The problem is that if you immediately select another drop down in another row you see the previous text typed in the text area in the modal window. AND . . . the same row data that was executed before is again executed with the current row's data. So I need to clear out the modal window and the previously set variables.

```
$('#my_window_textarea').val("");
grid.refresh();
grid.dataSource.read();
grid.dataSource.refresh();
grid.dataSource.sync();
$('#my_window').refresh();

var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
 ...
 dataBound: function(e) {
 ...
 $(".my_dropdown")
   dataTextField: "my_dp_name",
   dataValueField: "my_dp_field",
   optionLabel: "select something",
   dataSource: mydata,
   select: function(e){
       var grid = $(#grid).data("kendoGrid");
       var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this.wrapper.parents('tr'));

       var my_first_row_val = dataItem.first_id.toString();
       ....
       var dp_selection = e.dataItem.my_dp_name.toString();
       if(dp_selection == 'Something specific'){
          $('#my_dialog').modal();
          var validator = $('my_dialog').kendoValidator().data('kendoValidator');
          $('#btn_save').on("click",function(){
             if(validator.validate()){
                send('some/where/function', {
                  'my_first_row_val': my_first_row_val,
             }).fail(function(e) {
                   alert(e.responseText.toSource());
             }).done(function(e) {
                  $('my_dialog').modal('hide');
                  location.reload(true);
             });
           }
         });
```

The only solution that works is that inside "done" I call
      $('my_modal_dialog').modal('hide'); 
    and then 
      location.reload(true). 
but the page jumps which is not a good user experience.

Comment: You're saying that the previous request is being executed with the previous `id` ? Something like that ? As per the modal, you can clear it's contents before showing it with `$('#my_dialog .modal-body').empty()` for instance.

Comment: It performs the current request as well as the previous requests . . . yes.

Comment: turns out you have to add .off("click").on("click",function(){ to the button to discard the previous click event and only act up on the current one.